# SQLite UPDATE statement is doing nothing if column is quoted

Tags: sql, sqlite

I was trying to execute an SQL query on a sample table I made that looks like this:

```
name        text                                    number
----------------------------------------------------------
target      the cell to operate on                  5
cruft       cell here to simulate stuff happening   7
```

This is the SQL query I am trying to execute:

```
UPDATE data SET 'name'='target', 'number'=2 WHERE 'name'='target';
```

I expected this to change the 5 in the first row to a 2.

When I tried to execute this in [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) and eventually in the command-line sqlite version 3.7.13, it reported no error but didn't change the requested entry either. Oddly, if the quotes are removed from either string 'target' I get an error message saying `no such column: target` even though 'target' isn't being used as a column name. Removing the `'name'='target',` portion doesn't change anything.

Eventually I solved the immediate problem by removing the single quotes from `'name'` in the WHERE clause only, which is confounding.

```
UPDATE data SET 'name'='target', 'number'=3 WHERE name='target';
```

Does anyone know why this happens, or how I can work the quotes back in to protect against a hypothetical column name with a space in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were testing whether the string `'name'` was equal to the string `'target'`.

You should use double quotes for column-names:

```
UPDATE data SET "name"='target', "number"=3 WHERE "name"='target';
```

Reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes for string literals i.e. the value you want to assign to a column. Use double quotes for identifiers i.e. the names of columns or tables. See http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q24

So for your example it should read

```
UPDATE data SET "name"='target', "number"=2 WHERE "name"='target';
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are used for string constants.  In MySQL, use back ticks for variables names -- or better yet, nothing at all unless the name contains a reserved word or unusual character.  So:

```
UPDATE data
    SET name = 'target',
        number = 2
    WHERE name = 'target';
```

As a general rule, only use single quotes for string constants.